# Нахождение угла между 2 точками (для движения машины к цели)

Tags: c#

Проблема такая:

Нужно найти угол между точками X, Y.

К примеру, есть точки:

Координаты машины:

> x: 1141.513916
>   y: -1162.998169

Координаты точки, куда нужно ей приехать:

> x: 1162.112061
>   y: -1199.149658

Нужно как-то рассчитать угол между машиной и точкой.

Должно быть что-то такое:

```
if (angel < 5){
  Turn_Car_Left();
}

if (angel == 5){
  Ride_Forward();
}

if (angel > 5){
  Turn_Car_Right();
}
```

Comment: Угол между двумя точками? =/

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну да. Типа.. Чтобы знать, куда повернуть колёса машины

Comment: между двумя точками можно провести только прямую. у прямой нет углов. что бы был угол требуется 3 точки

Comment: наверное, имеется ввиду угол относительно направления север-юг...

Comment: Я так понимаю вам нужен угол между прямой, которую можно провести между двумя точками, и какой-то осью координатной плоскости (угол наклона прямой)? Такт тут можно воспользоваться тригонометрическими функциями..

Comment: учитывая, что это поворот колес, я подозреваю, что нужен угол между текущим направлением машины и требуемой точкой, но тогда требуется знать текущее направление машины. либо в виде 2х точек, либо в виде угла относительно чего либо, например одной из осей координат

Comment: именно, угол между вектором движения машины и двумя точками. типа пол решения здесь https://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC

Comment: @Mike, вся доступная информация - это X и Y машины. К сожалению, ничего больше.

Comment: @NoName_as_Null Вам уже объяснили, что между двумя точками угла быть не может. Так что, к сожалению, ответа на свой вопрос Вы не получите, пока не уточните обстоятельства

Comment: Я человек простой: пишу `ответа на свой вопрос Вы не получите`, после чего даю ответ)

Comment: Вам необходимо сохранять предыдущее значение точки.

Comment: @NoName_as_Null Вы стоите с завязанными глазами, вам известно что на юго-востоке находиться яма и вам надо сделать один шаг. вопрос: как надо повернуться, что бы не упасть в яму. Ваша машина сейчас в таком же положении. Очевидно, вы можете только гадать (так как не знаете, не смотрите ли вы сейчас на юго-восток). Однако, если вы перед этим уже делали шаг или если вы знаете, что развернуты к северу, то задача из не разрешимой, становится тривиальной. Так что ваш единственный путь - пересмотреть всю задачу и найти какие нибудь дополнительные данные для расчета, например историю движения

Comment: Или, как вариант сделать очень странную функцию движения, которая будет после каждого движения разворачивать вас строго на север. Зная координаты и что вы сейчас смотрите на север, вы всегда можете рассчитать угол до нужной точки, повернуть на него, сделать шаг, развернуться на минус тот же угол. Вы опять смотрите на север и можете при следующем входе в функцию спокойно все расчитать

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Вступление

Итак, начать стоит с того, что Вы поставили **некорректное** условие, так как [угол](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB) -

> геометрическая фигура, образованная двумя лучами (сторонами угла), выходящими из одной точки (которая называется вершиной угла).

В свою очередь [луч](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D1%87_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)) -

> часть прямой, состоящая из данной точки и всех точек, лежащих по одну сторону от неё. Любая точка на прямой разделяет прямую на два луча.

В свою же очередь одна единственная [прямая](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F) проходит через **2 точки** => для построения угла требуется части 2-х пересекающихся прямых (с одной общей точкой) => 2 * 2 - 1 = **3 точки**

Таким образом мы получаем очевидный для всех факт: **не может быть** между двумя точками какого-либо угла

---

### Немного теории

Отойдем ненадолго от разъяснений геометрии за N класс средней школы и все таки попытаемся догадаться, что же Вам нужно

Как я понимаю, Вы моделируете движение машины в плоскости `xOy`. Так как машина движется, она имеет некоторый [вектор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)), характеризующий ее перемещение.

Предположу, что машина выехала из точки **(0; 0)** => если ее текущие координаты равны **(x; y)**, то вектор перемещения равен { x - 0; y - 0; } = **{ x; y; }**

Однако так как Вам требуется найти угол для поворота машины, Вам бы следовало использовать вектор ее [скорости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C), но Вы нас обделили информацией о нем, так что предположу, что он сонаправлен с вектором перемещения

Итак. На данном шаге у нас есть [вектор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)) и [точка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)), итого: **3 точки**. Для расчета угла более чем достаточно

Далее находим направляющий вектор из начала координат в необходимую точку и находим наименьший угол между двумя имеющимися векторами (`a` и `b`) по формуле:

```
cos(α) = (a * b) / (|a| * |b|)
```

---

### Пример

Попробуем на примере:

Пусть машина располагается в точке **(1; 2.5)**, а пункт назначения - в точке **(3; 3)**:

[image: пример]

`a` = **{ 1; 2.5 }**
`b` = **{ 3; 3 }**

```
cos(α) = (1*3 + 2.5*3) / (sqrt(1*1 + 2.5*2.5) * sqrt(3*3 + 3*3)) ≈ 0.91914503001
```

=>

```
α = arccos(0.91914503001) ≈ 0.404891786 rad ≈ 23.1985905 deg
```

Вот мы и получили заветный угол, который примерно равен **23 градусам**

На сием курс геометрии окончен, переходим к программной реализации

---

### Реализация

Набросаем такую функцию:

```
private static double GetAngle(Point Machine, Point Destination)
{
    // Получим косинус угла по формуле
    double cos = Math.Round((Machine.X * Destination.X + Machine.Y * Destination.Y) / (Math.Sqrt(Machine.X * Machine.X + Machine.Y * Machine.Y) * Math.Sqrt(Destination.X * Destination.X + Destination.Y * Destination.Y)), 9);
    // Вернем arccos полученного значения (в радианах!)
    return Math.Acos(cos);
}
```

Судя по значениям в Вашем примере, которые явно больше единицы, Вы используете не [радианную](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD), а [градусную](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)) меру, а посему значение, которое вернет Вам функция, необходимо будет преобразовать по формуле:

```
dAngle = rAngle * 180 / Pi
```

То есть так:

```
// Переведем угол в градусы
private static double ToDegrees(double Angle) => Angle * 180 / Math.PI;
```

---

Протестируем:

Пусть машина располагается в точке **(-3; -3)**, а пункт назначения - в точке **(3; 3)**:

[image: пример2]

Найдем угол:

```
Console.WriteLine(ToDegrees(GetAngle(new Point(-3, -3), new Point(3, 3)))); // 180
```

**180 градусов**, что, очевидно, является чистейшей правдой!

---

### Итоги

Старайтесь не забывать, что программирование состоит не только из набора текста, но и из применения **знаний** некой предметной области, с которой Вы соприкасаетесь в рамках проекта.

Чего-то не знаете? Читайте и узнавайте по теме как можно больше!

И да, подчеркну, что представленный выше метод будет работать **только** если Ваша машинка прямолинейно **удаляется** от начала координат (т.е. векторы перемещения и скорости сонаправлены), однако стоит машине развернуться и поехать в сторону точки (0; 0), как все сломается! 
Чтобы решить проблему, Вам необходимо знать, в какую сторону движется автомобиль. Я не знаю деталей Вашей реализации, так что могу предложить кэшировать предыдущую точку, в которой был автомобиль, после чего уже передвигать его на новую. Тем самым Вы спокойно в любой момент времени найдете вектор скорости машины и примените его в расписанном выше алгоритме

Comment: Чрезмерно Вам благодарен! Да, Вы правы, я допустил ошибку, когда написал "нахождение угла"

Comment: @NoName_as_Null если Вам нужно, могу набросать пример реализации

Comment: если Вам не трудно - набросайте, пожалуйста)

Comment: хм.. Там интересная история получается. Суть в том, что при отдалении от чекпоинта - GetAngel начинает увеличиваться. То есть, получается так, что я не могу подобрать условие, при котором машине нужно поворачивать в ту или иную сторону, ибо при разном отдалении от чекпоинта (даже если поставить машину под 90 градусов к чекпоинту) - GetAngel разный. Машина может стоять прям нос в нос с чекпоинтом, но при этом GetAngel будет выдавать не "90", к примеру, а ещё какие-нибудь значения. Как с этим быть? :( Нужно именно выравнивать машину отностительно чекпоинта, чтобы она туда попала.

Comment: @NoName_as_Null именно поэтому и нужен вектор скорости) Завтра покажу, как это выглядит с простеньким примером на PictureBox в WinForms)

Comment: был бы очень благодарен. Кстати, сейчас навешал на машину дополнительно датчиков. Теперь, помимо координат, известно: Направление движения (от 0 до 360 градусов), скорость.

Comment: @NoName_as_Null можете добавить конкретики в вопрос: 0-360° относительно чего? Оси `oX`?

Comment: вообще, там получается 0-360 - это ось Z

Comment: @NoName_as_Null у Вас же двумерное пространство, откуда взялась третья ось? И если направление машины задается по этой оси, она у Вас, простите, куда-то «улетает» относительно основной плоскости?

Comment: под "ось z" я имел ввиду, что 0-360 - это как бы поворачивается середина машины. Относительно чего... Если честно, то я сам не знаю)

Comment: @NoName_as_Null ох. Трудно помогать человеку, который не знает, что он знает... хД Вы можете хоть картинку дать, где показать, что это за 0-360°?

Comment: секунду, сейчас видео запишу.

Comment: @NoName_as_Null можно без видео. Давайте так: пробросьте Вашу машину из одной точки в другую, запишите, чему был равен этот ваш угол и пришлите мне координаты двух точек и угол. Если значения не уложатся во что-то вразумительное: тогда прибегнем к видео)

Comment: вот видео: https://youtu.be/HkBf-TGDAI4

Comment: видео, с тестом GetAngel: https://youtu.be/bZfOiU2946o

Comment: @NoName_as_Null так, я понял, сейчас попробую высчитать, относительно какой оси берётся этот самый угол поворота

Comment: @NoName_as_Null оформите, пожалуйста, вопрос, в котором укажите именно угол поворота машины, а также прикрепите к нему указанное два видео-ролика и ссылку на этот вопрос, как логическую отправную точку) Кажется, я эмпирически нащупал механику Вашей игры и готов дать ответ (и скиньте сюда в комментарии ссылку на новый вопрос, а то могу не отмониторить))

Comment: хорошо, сейчас все сделаю

Comment: готово, вроде как) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870895/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

Считаю, что дано:

```
S: точка, координаты машины  
D: вектор направления машины  
T: целевая точка
```

Тогда целевой вектор

```
V = T - S 
  //или в компонентах:
V.X = T.X - S.X
V.Y = T.Y - S.Y
```

Угол между текущим направлением машины и целевым вектором

```
A = atan2(D x V, D * V)  //векторное и скалярное произведение векторов 
  //или в компонентах:
A = atan2(D.X * V.Y - D.Y * V.X, D.X * V.X + D.Y * V.Y)
```

Результат - угол в радианах в диапазоне `-Pi..Pi`, на который нужно повернуть машину, чтобы мгновенный вектор её направления указывал на цель.

Знак угла соответствует левому или правому повороту.

*(физику (инерцию и т.д.), как я понял, не учитываем)*