# Нахождение траектории для движения автомобиля

Tags: c#, математика

Логическое продолжение [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/869222/248572)

Мне посоветовали метод, использующий вектор скорости, который я напрямую получить не могу. Я добавил машине новых датчиков, так что опишу вопрос, исходя из новых доступных данных данных

---

Суть проблемы:

Есть автомобиль и конечная точка. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы автомобиль попал в эту точку, а именно вычислить тот угол, на который нужно повернуть автомобилю, чтобы попасть на координаты точки.

Что известно:

**Автомобиль:**

1. Координаты X и Y
2. Угол поворота автомобиля (0-360°, относительно чего - неизвестно)
3. Скорость автомобиля

**Конечная точка (checkpoint):**

1. Лишь Координаты X и Y

---

Я записал несколько видео, где чуть-чуть видно данные, получаемые от датчиков машины:

1. [Один](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkBf-TGDAI4&feature=youtu.be)
2. [Два](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZfOiU2946o&feature=youtu.be)

Пример данных из видео, описывающих перемещение машины:

> **X:** 1376.125
>   **Y:** 1262.289
>   **Rotation:** 118.14453125
>   **X:** 1374.959
>   **Y:** 1261.684

---

Мой вопрос: как рассчитывается угол поворота машины и как, исходя из этих данных, получить угол, на который надо повернуть машину, чтобы она достигла нужной точки?

Comment: Из видео - ничего не понятно.

Comment: Найти угол прямой с (0,0) по отношению к  ОХ ?

Comment: Вы не можете вычислить разницу между курсом автомобиля и направлением на чекпоинт? И почему "угол" в кавычках, вы что-то иное в этом понимаете?

Comment: Строишь попендикуляр к текущей траектории через текущую точку.Строишь отрезок между текущей и конечной точками. Строишь попендикуляр через его середину. Точка пересечения попендикуляров есть центр радиуса поворота. Не исключено, что ехать-то надо и ни разу и не вперёд...

Comment: а скорось у вас относительно x и y, или просто скорость, без направления?

Comment: Я так понял, нужно рассматривать автомобиль не как математическую точку, а как объект с размерами. И нужно не просто переместить объект из одной точки в другую, а при этом поворачивать его ось в направлении движения, да еще учитывать его минимальный радиус поворота. Гуглите по словам "аппроксимация", "сплайн", "кривая Безье".

Comment: @ГеннадийП, верно. Необходимо найти какое-то значение направления автомобиля, чтобы можно было в условии сделать что-то типа: if (angle_to_checkpoint > 0) turn_left(); else if (angle_to_checkpoint < 0) turn_right(); else just_ride_forward();

Comment: @Monomax, вообще, там скорость по X и по Y. Просто преобразована через Math.Sqrt. Полный код скорости добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @NoName_as_Null статья старенькая, но полезная: https://habr.com/post/131931/ - там найдете ответы на все свои вопросы

Comment: Товарищи, ну что это такое? Заминусовали вопрос человека за незнание. Мы же тут как раз и помогаем разбираться в том, чего человек не понимает

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Первые пару ревизий вопроса откройте, там по сути только `Необходимо сделать так, чтобы..`, некоторые данные и ссылки на видео, где не понятно что делается. Видать, поэтому и наставили минусы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, давайте разбираться, откуда берется этот *угол поворота машины*!

Угол поворота имеет смысл в том случае, когда нам есть от чего отклоняться. То есть в нашем двумерном пространстве есть некоторая прямая, от которой и считается этот самый угол наклона. Логично предположить, что это одна из осей: `Ox` или `Oy`

Так как пишете Вы для `SA:MP`, который базируется на `GTA SA`, пытающемся повторять реальную жизнь в некоторых аспектах, то одна из осей скорее всего сонаправлена с игровым севером, от которого и логично было бы считать подобное отклонение

Пусть с игровым севером сонаправлена ось `Oy`. Проверим нашу теорию на Ваших данных:

> **X:** 1376.125
>   **Y:** 1262.289
>   **Rotation:** 118.14453125
>   **X:** 1374.959
>   **Y:** 1261.684

То есть машина переместилась из `(1376.125; 1262.289)` в `(1374.959; 1261.684)`, имея при этом угол наклона  ≈ `118º`

Найдем вектор скорости:

**V** = { 1374.959 - 1376.125; 1261.684 - 1262.289} **= { -1.166; -0.605 }**

Теперь найдем угол между ним и вектором, задающим положительное направление оси `Oy` (единичный вектор `j`), то есть вектором **{ 0; 1 }**:

```
cos(α) = (0*-1.166 + 1*-0.605) / (sqrt(0*0 + 1*1) * sqrt(-1.166*-1.166 + -0.605*-0.605)) ≈ -0.4605615728
```

=>

```
α = arccos(-0.4605615728) ≈ 2.04942409 rad ≈ 117.423351 deg ≈ 118 deg
```

собственно, мы как раз и получили что-то около искомых `118º` за вычетом погрешности измерений и вычислений)

Также стоит заметить, что полученный [радиус-вектор](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjWjLOD5PrcAhUmQpoKHaHyBYsQFjABegQICxAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25A0%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B8%25D1%2583%25D1%2581-%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BA%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580&usg=AOvVaw2KCIYwfUz0VIbO-LMzpMTn) располагается в третьей четверти, а угол при этом меньше 180º (исходя из Вашего условия, угол поворота рассчитывается от 0 до 360 градусов) => отсчет идет **против** часовой стрелки. Возможно, вывод ошибочен, однако полученные данные слишком похожи на реальные, а исходить нам больше не из чего, так что примем за данность)

---

Теперь мы знаем, как считается *угол поворота Вашей машины*!

Так что от нас просто требуется найти такой же угол между [радиус-вектором](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjWjLOD5PrcAhUmQpoKHaHyBYsQFjABegQICxAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25A0%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B8%25D1%2583%25D1%2581-%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BA%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580&usg=AOvVaw2KCIYwfUz0VIbO-LMzpMTn), идущим в точку назначения, и единичным вектором `j`!
Сделаем это так:

```
// Получим угол между радиус-вектором точки назначения и вектором j
public static double GetRotation(Point Destination)
{
    // Получим косинус угла
    double cos = Destination.Y / Math.Sqrt(Destination.X * Destination.X + Destination.Y * Destination.Y);
    //Получим сам угол
    double angle = Math.Acos(cos);
    // Если мы в первой или четвертой четвертях, то отнимем от полного оборота
    // полученное значение
    // Если отсчет идет все же ПО ЧАСОВОЙ, то сменить знак '>' на '<'!
    if (Destination.X > 0)
        angle = 2 * Math.PI - angle;
    return angle;
}
// Перевод из rad в deg
public static double ToDegrees(double Angle) => Angle * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Вот и готово. У нас есть угол поворота машины относительно `Oy`, а также угол поворота [радиус-вектора](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjWjLOD5PrcAhUmQpoKHaHyBYsQFjABegQICxAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25A0%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B8%25D1%2583%25D1%2581-%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BA%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580&usg=AOvVaw2KCIYwfUz0VIbO-LMzpMTn) точки назначения относительной этой же оси. Остается вычесть первое из второго, получив тем самым угол, на который Вашей машине нужно повернуть!

```
double machineRotation = ...;
car.Rotate(ToDegrees(GetRotation(destination)) - machineRotation);
```

---

Искренне надеюсь, что Ваша проблема наконец разрешилась и Вы сможете дальше продолжать двигаться к своим свершениям!

Comment: Поправка: считать угол против часовой стрелки как раз логично - потому что это традиционное для математики направление отсчета угла (от оси X к оси Y)

Comment: @PavelMayorov оу, как-то умудрялся этого не замечать...) Позор на мою голову хД Ладно, спасибо

Comment: @PavelMayorov что-то я не подумал, что углы на той же единичной окружности считаются именно против часовой, надо больше спать ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, огромное спасибо! Всё работает! Наконец-то... Я уж думал бросать эту затею... В общем , огромное человеческое спасибо Вам!

Comment: @NoName_as_Null рад, что таки смог Вам помочь)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я совершенно далек от языка C#, но ваш ответ читал с удовольствием и даже, кажется, кое-что понял. :) Так хорошо вы всегда отвечаете (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо большое) // краснеет